# GitLabee Authentication failed

Tags: git, authentication, openssh, access-denied, gitlab-ee

There is a repository i always use in Gitlabee. When I tried '`git pull origin modal_control`' in git bash, openSSH tab opens and ask to me username and password.

I entered the username and passwaord. But git bash gives me this output:

```
$ git pull origin modal_control
  remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
  remote: You must use a personal access token with 'read_repository' or 
  'write_repository' scope for Git over HTTP.
  remote: You can generate one at 
  https://gitlabee....com/-/profile/personal_access_tokens
  fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlabee....com/__repository_name__'
```

I created access tokens and SSH key but it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double check which username you used: SSH should not ask for username/password, since GitLab EE only uses the technical service account '`git`' (whose password is not public anyway)

Since the authentication has failed for an HTTPS URL, SSH should not be involved at all, and the username asked is indeed your Gitlabee account name.

That means you must enter as password your [Gitlabee token (PAT)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/index.html#personalproject-access-tokens), not your actual password.
Meaning once you have [created your PAT](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html), you can use it as your password, when prompted for a password.

Comment: How can i found this password? Actually, i do not get it :/

Comment: @sudesanlii "this password"? Password of which username? 'git'? Or your own GitLab EE user account?

Comment: 'That means you must enter as password your Gitlabee token (PAT), not your actual password.'  the password you mentioned here

Comment: @sudesanlii The PAT (Personnal Access Token): you find/create it following the documentation: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html. And then use it as a password.

Comment: I already have access token. I created it using the documentation (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) . But It doesn't want me to create a password while doing this.

Comment: @sudesanlii If you have a token, you can simply use it as your password. No need to "create a password".

Answer (score 0):

Solution: You have to create access token in gitlabee. Then, you can try again. When opened the openSSH tab, usurname is access token name and password is access token password.